# Get the differences between 2 maps flutter

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have 2 maps and I want to get the missing elements as a list. For example:

```
var map1= [
   {"name":"name1","email":"name1@email.com"},
   {"name":"name2","email":"name2@email.com"},
   {"name":"name3","email":"name3@email.com"},
 ];
   var map2= [
   {"name":"name1","email":"name1@email.com"},
   {"name":"name2","email":"name2@email.com"},
  
 ];

Output: [{"name":"name3","email":"name3@email.com"}]
```

I tried this approach:

```
var removedElements = map2.where((element) => 
                                      !map1
                                          .contains(element['email']))
                                      .toList();
```

but it doesn't work. Any help would be great.

Comment: please have a look. let me know, is it working for you?

Comment: you are welcome mate; Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
void main() {
  var map1 = [
    {"name": "name1", "email": "name1@email.com"},
    {"name": "name2", "email": "name2@email.com"},
    {"name": "name3", "email": "name3@email.com"},
  ];
  var map2 = [
    {"name": "name1", "email": "name1@email.com"},
    {"name": "name2", "email": "name2@email.com"},
  ];

  var removedElements = [];
  var k;
  for (var i in map2) {
    for (var j in map1) {
      if (i["email"] != j["email"]) {
        k = j;
      }
    }
     removedElements.add(k);
  }

  print(removedElements.toSet().toList());
}
```

Another approach

```
 var removedElements =
      map2.where((element) {
       for(var i in map1){
         if(i["email"] == element["email"]){
           return false;
         } else{
           return true;
         }
       }
      }).toList();

  print(removedElements);
```

**output**
: [{name: name3, email: name3@email.com}]